# What is the best way to sample from a gaussian in Haskell using the statistics package?

Tags: haskell, statistics

I am trying to create a gaussian distribution in Haskell and sample individual Doubles from that distribution. I am using the [NormalDistribution](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics-0.15.2.0/docs/Statistics-Distribution-Normal.html#t:NormalDistribution) type from the [statistics](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics-0.15.2.0) package, and I think I have created something that works via that type's instance of [ContGen](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics-0.15.2.0/docs/Statistics-Distribution.html#t:ContGen):

```
ghci> withSystemRandom (genContVar (normalDistr 0 1) :: (Gen (PrimState IO) -> IO Double))
-0.2029152322129268
```

Without going into detail, this involves importing modules from [mwc-random](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mwc-random-0.14.0.0) (for `withSystemRandom`) and [primitive](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive) (for the type annotation, which is required for this to run). In the past, working with primitive has usually meant that I missed a higher level api in the package I was trying to use.

Is there a way to sample from gaussians via `statistics` and without the need for `primitive`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not really *working with primitive* there. Just, `withSystemRandom` happens to instantiate the generator with `PrimState IO`, but that's an implementation detail that you don't really need to be concerned with. Just write [`GenIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mwc-random-0.14.0.0/docs/System-Random-MWC.html#t:GenIO) instead of `Gen (PrimState IO)`, then you also don't need to explicitly depend on the `primitive` package.